# VSCode is showing "cannot open source file" error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm unable to include standard libraries in vscode.

I'm trying to run simple codes like:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

But it's the following error msg:
**Error message:**
cannot open source file "bits/libc-header-start.h" (dependency of "stdio.h")

I'm totally new to UBUNTU and i was setting up my programming tools. But this is where i've been stucked.

I've tried googling it but failed to get the solution. I've reinstalled the GCC compiler.
I've tried to change the compiler path to **/usr/bin/gcc**

Comment: did you follow https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux ?

Comment: yes, i did followed that.